# System tries to install grub on usb instead of ssd

Tags: 14.04, server, partitioning, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu server on my storage server. The problem starts in partition manager when the system wants the usb that i'm installing it from to be the system hdd. I change it to the ssd, but when i get to the end the system gives me an grub error that say "fail when trying to install grub to hdd (sdb)", where "sdb" is the USB. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can most likely remedy this by manually installing grub on your desired HD.

Try running this sequence exactly:

Boot to a live try Ubuntu session, then run the following at a terminal prompt:

```
a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt # Make "sdaX" the partition that has Ubuntu install (i.e. /dev/sda2)
b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
c) sudo chroot /mnt
d) update-grub
e) if no errors skip this "e" section
     grub-install /dev/sdX (sdX is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
     update-grub 5) Reboot the system
```

After you have performed the manual steps be sure to set your computer bios to have your desired boot drive as the default boot device.

Answer (score 0):

Think i just solved the same Problem.

When you're asked wheather you want to install Grub to the MBR select 'No'. It seems stupid but this will not cancel the grub-install process instead you will be asked to which device grub should be installed now. Enter /dev/sdX according to your needs

I hope this applies. But I guess so as you're talking of a server.
Greets

Fot Others:
In my case I was using the alternate Install of Lubuntu 14.04.1 i386(32bit).

I guess it applies to the debian-installer (in ubuntu alternate-iso) in general.

I'm experiencing it when I choose "Expert install" or "Install" but not when I use "Install lubuntu" because this will hide the pendrive and install MBR to the HDD